# How to stop automatic redirection of webpages in Safari browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

So let's just say I have 4 web-pages - Page A, Page B, Page C, Page D.

Page A is the home page and has three hyperlinks ( tag) to Page B, Page C and Page D.

Pages B,C and D have a back button. On clicking the back-button, `window.history.back()` function is called.

When I click on the hyperlink to 'Page B', it opens the Page B perfectly. However, on clicking the back button, it opens the 'Page A' for 1 brief second before automatically opening the 'Page D' which is the last link on 'Page A'.

Once on 'Page D', if I press the back button again, it takes me back to 'Page A' and does not redirect me again to the 'Page D'.

Here is my code for reference:

```
$(".back_button").on("click",function(e){
  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android")!= -1){
      window.history.back();
      return false;
  } else if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone")!= -1){
       //history.go(-1);
       window.history.back();
       return false;
  }
})
```

I encounter this issue only when I'm using Safari webkit on iOS devices. On android phones or the Chrome browser, this does not cause a problem.

I searched everywhere, but couldn't find a solution to this. Can anyone help me?